# Can not build application for Android (.Net 7)

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

At first Visual Studio said me to restore workloads, but when I tried it I always got an error. After changing versions number in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\` I finally restored workloads. After it I got the following error on build:
`Unable to find package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android with version (=52.1.0)`
`Unable to find package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android with version (=52.1.0)`
[error on build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ0zz.png)

Errors full text:

```
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android with version (= 52.1.0)
  - Found 31 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 7.0.59 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs
```

```
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android with version (= 52.1.0)
  - Found 31 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 7.0.59 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
  - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Do not post errors as images

Comment: Added errors full text

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by changing version number in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maui` from `51.1.0` to `7.0.59`